# B2C- Unable to hide element with JS in my custom policy

Tags: javascript, css, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In my custom policy, I try to hide **email_intro** label but without success :
[image: validateEmail]

**- This is my html code :**

```
<div id="api" data-name="Unified">
    <form id="attributeVerification">
        <div id="attributeList" class="attr">
            <ul>
                ...
                <li class="TextBox">
                    <div class="attrEntry">
                        <div>
                            <div class="verificationInfoText" id="email_intro" style="display: 
                            inline;" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="polite" 
                            role="alert">Verification is necessary. Please click Send button. 
                            </div>
                        ...
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </li>
                ...                             
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            ...         
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**- My JS code**

```
var intro = document.getElementById("email_intro");
intro.style.setProperty('display','none');
```

Could someone know what the error might be please?

PS : I do the same thing to other elements and it works!!

Comment: It seems to be working fine [in a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micahlt/8fy5q2mt/).  It looks like another stylesheet may be causing the issue, in which case you'll have to use the [`!important` modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception).

Comment: You also have a mismatch in your tags. 9 opening tags vs 8 closing tags. Based on the indentation, the missing end tag would come after the "Verification ..." text.

Comment: @micahlt I try with **intro.style.setProperty('display','none','important');** but also doesn't work

Comment: @Ouroborus it was a mistake, I edit it in the question. But still doesn't work

Comment: @Nicolas can you confirm that the style is being set by using your browser's devtools?  Or is the style not being set at all?

Comment: The only css style attached to this element is for the class name : 
`.verificationInfoText {
    font-weight: bold;
}`

Comment: @micahlt I don't use a browser's devtools, I just create a css file and referenced it in my Html page.

Comment: So target that class name (`.verificationInfoText`) when applying the style.

Comment: I have other elements with the same class name, and only **email_intro** should be hided.

Comment: @micahlt you were right, I inspecte the page and that was an other stylesheet injected `element.style {display: inline; }`
Thanks. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@micahlt you were right, I inspecte the page and that was an other stylesheet injected `element.style {display: inline; }`
Thanks. It works

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17574543/nicolas) and [micahlt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10806546/micahlt) for your valuable discussions. Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> This seems to be an issue occurred due to style sheet miss match.
> Targeting the correct style sheet [`element.style {display: inline; }`] to class name (`.verificationInfoText`) solved the issue.